# c++ function returning variable length

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the length of the returning value of the function, When I calculate stuff it gives me varibles with different length, thats why I cant sum them and compare.

For example: the function calculates the length of the line AC it gives 4.24264
the line AC consists of two other lines AB and BC which are AB = 0.942809 and BC=3.29983
when you sum AB and BC it equals of 4.242639 but the same function gives 4.24264, so C++ does not say that they are equal, so how do I change that?

EDIT: function returns double and all of the variables are double

Comment: `double` or `float` numbers are almost never equal. You need to compare them with some accuracy... e.g. `fabs(x-y) < 1.0e-6*max(fabs(x),fabs(y))`

Comment: every type in my code is double

Comment: Here's a good read for you:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/42980

Comment: Post your code that calculates the values!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're dealing with float / double comparison. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison) might help.